# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in multiple images uploading

Tags: php, image, file-upload, foreach

I am trying to upload multiple image files and rename them as user supplied name. After receiving the POST parameters(like filename, department_id etc.).

But the following code gives me a warning "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 11", which is the foreach() containing line. Any possible error source ? Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
    include_once './classes/functions.php';
    if (isset($_POST['sendfiles'])) {
            $filename = $_POST['filename'];
            $department_id = $_POST['department_id'];
            $reg_no = $_POST['reg_no'];
            $fiscal_year = $_POST['fiscal_year'];
            $tags = $_POST['tags'];
            $fileName_array = "";
            $new_file_id = get_new_id('files');
             foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value) {
                $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
                //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
                $extension = getExtension($filename);
                $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //            echo "\n This is the extension: ", $extension;
                if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) {

                    header("Location:../add_new_file.php?msg=error_file_type");
    //                $errors = 1;
                } else {
                    $size = filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);
                    if ($size > 5000 * 1024) {
                        header("Location:../add_new_file.php?msg=error_file_size");
    //                    $errors = 1;
                    }
                    $image_name = $filename . '.' . $extension;
                    $newname = 'department_' . $department_id . '/' . $new_file_id . '_' . $image_name;
    //                $new_file_id++;
                    $fileName_array += $newname . ',';
                    $copied = copy($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname);
                    if (!$copied) {
                        header('Location: ../add_new_file.php?msg=error_upload_file');
                    }
                }
            }
    //        if (add_new_file($filename, $department_id, $reg_no, $fiscal_year, $tags, $fileName_array) == true) {
    //            return true;
    //        }
    //        return false;
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line No. 1 returns `false`.

If you upload multiple files - `$_FILES['photos']['name']` is an array of multiple names.

You can try this:

```
echo '<pre>';echo print_r($_FILES['photos']['name']);echo '</pre>';exit();
```

I had a code similar to yours. It worked when using small size files, but failed with big ones. The following error was displayed:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in multiple images uploading

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['photos']['name']` in your `foreach` line is a string, not an array.

You can see the structure of the `$_FILES` array by calling `print_r($_FILES)`.

You might want something like:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    $filename = stripslashes($file['name']);
    ....
}
```

You would then want to replace all mentions of `$_FILES['photos']` with `$file` inside the `foreach` block.